# How should I set up tables, and items for my current scenario with dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I have two types of users, `children`, and `parents`.

`children` enter money they have earned with the date and time they have earned it. They also have a list of users who can access what they have earned, which are `parents`. I'll eventually add triggers that notify parents if they earned more than, say, $20 at a given input.

`parents` simply have a list of `children`, and can see what these `children` have earned.

I was wondering on a good way to implement this. My approach is as follows, using partition key and sort key:

Table 1: `children` 
Income will be formatted as such:

```
[
  {
    childId: 100,
    sharedUsers: {ParentID1, ParentID2, ...},
    childEarnings: [
      {
        earningID: 123123,
        amount: 15,
        date: 1/1/17
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*

I'm not sure if this is proper, as I don't know what I should use for sort key. It would be nice for it to be sorted by date, and also have another sort key by amount?

Any thoughts are appreciated

P.S. Table 2 was going to contain a list of parents, where each parent simply has the childID so they can then access all those child's earnings

Comment: What are your query requirements? Design of tables depends on that

Comment: Can you elaborate, or provide an example of a query requirement?

Comment: For example, what type of queries will you need to execute? Is it just get a parent by ID then get his children or get a child by ID and get his parents? You mentioned sort keys. What type of queries do you plan to use with them?